# Unable to publish my 3rd script Pine-script external link error

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to publish my 3rd script in tradingview, but it gives me an error saying that I need to be a PRO member with 10 reps to be able to publish with external link. My code has not external links. Can you help, please? My code is as below:

```
//@version=4
study("Spread Chart", shorttitle="Spread Chart")

//Input
operator = input(title="Operator", defval="/", options=["/", "+", "-", "*", "1/N"])
comparativeTickerId = input("NSE:NIFTY", type=input.symbol, title="Comparative Symbol") 
showMA = input(defval=false, type=input.bool, title="Show Close Moving Average")
lengthMA = input(50, type=input.integer, minval=1, title="Close Moving Average Period")

//Set up
cs_o = security(comparativeTickerId, timeframe.period, open) 
cs_h = security(comparativeTickerId, timeframe.period, high) 
cs_l = security(comparativeTickerId, timeframe.period, low) 
cs_c = security(comparativeTickerId, timeframe.period, close) 

bs_o = security(syminfo.tickerid, timeframe.period, open) 
bs_h = security(syminfo.tickerid, timeframe.period, high) 
bs_l = security(syminfo.tickerid, timeframe.period, low) 
bs_c = security(syminfo.tickerid, timeframe.period, close) 

op_open = (operator == "/" ? bs_o/cs_o : operator == "+" ? bs_o + cs_o : operator == "-" ? bs_o - cs_o : operator == "*" ? bs_o * cs_o : operator == "1/N" ? 1/bs_o : na)
op_high = (operator == "/" ? bs_h/cs_h : operator == "+" ? bs_h + cs_h : operator == "-" ? bs_h - cs_h : operator == "*" ? bs_h * cs_h : operator == "1/N" ? 1/bs_h : na)
op_low = (operator == "/" ? bs_l/cs_l : operator == "+" ? bs_l + cs_l : operator == "-" ? bs_l - cs_l : operator == "*" ? bs_l * cs_l : operator == "1/N" ? 1/bs_l : na)
op_close = (operator == "/" ? bs_c/cs_c : operator == "+" ? bs_c + cs_c : operator == "-" ? bs_c - cs_c : operator == "*" ? bs_c * cs_c : operator == "1/N" ? 1/bs_c : na)


//Plot
plotcandle(op_open, op_high, op_low, op_close, color = op_close > op_open ? color.green : color.red)
plot(showMA ? sma(op_close, lengthMA) : na)
```

Comment: Maybe the publication's description contain the link?

Comment: Thanks for the response. No, it doesn't. Not a sign of any like. Infact if I just create a blank study from the template and try to publish it, even then it is giving me the same error!!!

Comment: Contact support.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did contact, it seems I needed to be at least Pro user to contact them. However, I found that if I used the word "Spread" in the title or description it was giving the error. I not 100% sure, but when I changed the title it worked for me.